# How to generate json schema using spring-hateoas api

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-data-rest, jsonschema, spring-hateoas

I wan't to integrate https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form on my reactjs client application

I have an http API made with spring, spring-data-rest and spring-hateoas.

I would like to generate the json schema (IETF JSON Schema Internet Draft Version 4) for my form validation.

I know spring-data-rest using jackson as serializer.

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to do very little, spring-data-rest already [generates](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#metadata.json-schema) JSON Schema for you.

Here is the call for their example Person resource:

```
curl -H 'Accept:application/schema+json' http://localhost:8080/profile/persons
```